# Create an event that runs every 24 hours?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I have a Swift data file in the "Quote a Day" project with 500 quotes and I would like to call `updateQuote()` every time it becomes a new day.

The quote string variable updates a UILabel in the `QuoteViewcontroller` and the string for the alertBody in `UILocalNotifiication()`.

See below for reference:

```
var quotes:[Quote] = quoteData
var quote: String!
var counter = 0


func updateQuote() {

    if counter == quotes.count {

        counter = 0

    } else {

        quote = quotes[counter].quoteTitle

        counter++ 
    }
}
```

I was trying to do something like this with `NSDate()`:

```
let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dayCalendarUnit: NSCalendarUnit = [.Day]
let DayDifference = userCalendar.components(
    dayCalendarUnit,
    fromDate: lastDate,
    toDate: nowDate,
    options: [])

var difference = DayDifference.day

if difference > 0 {

updateQuote()
lastDate = nowDate 
}
```

But that logic does not seem to work as I am not sure how to populate lastDate and nowDate on the initial run.

I also I am not sure where to put the above function so that it can keep checking while the app is running in the background.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: There is no place for you to put that function so it will "keep running in the background." That would kill battery life so Apple doesn't allow it.

Comment: A local notification only invokes your code if the user taps it. If they don't it will just keep delivering the same text. The OP actually has a few questions here; 1. How to handle the initial date comparison? (trivial, just check for nil) but more significantly 2. How to keep,checking in the background? This isn't really possible. I have seen many similar questions on so. Some possible solutions are 1. Push notification. 2. Background fetch 3. Schedule multiple local notifications for consecutive days at once and update these when you app launches. 3 is probably best if you have no server

Comment: Alexis, when do you want the new quote to be displayed, inside the app when it is opened by the user or inside a local notification? If it is the latter then you will want to use scheduleLocalNotification(_ notification: UILocalNotification).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the app to show a different quote in a UILabel each day, then the obvious solution is to convert today's date into an integer and then index into your array using that integer. Something like this would do it...

```
let daysSince1970 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 / 60 / 60 / 24
let index = Int(daysSince1970) % quotes.count
myLabel.text = quotes[index]
```

The above code doesn't have to run constantly, it only has to run when the app is moved to the foreground.

To put the quote of the day in a notification... Somewhere in your UI you should be asking the user what time they want the quote delivered. Once you have that time, load up several one shot notifications each with a different quote in it and set to deliver on different days (choose the quote with the same algorithm as above, except advance the index once for each day.) I think Apple allows you to load 64 notifications this way.

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much, Daniel.  I am going to try the above to see if it will work.  You are right in thinking I want the daily quote label to be displayed when the user opens the app on any time that day.  And in addition, have that day's quote delivered in a local notification based on time settings inputted by the user.